# align environment multiline equations - starting equality and inequality slightly from left the avoid page cutoff

Tags: equations, align, lengths

I am using `align` environment to write quite huge multiline equations. The following latex source code generates the following screenshot

```
\begin{align}
        \Bigl\|\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\phi(s_t^i,a_t^i)[\bigl(\overline{V}^{k}_{t+1} - \mathbb{P}_t\overline{V}^{k}_{t+1}\bigr) (s_t^i, a_t^i)]\Bigr\|_{(\Sigma_t^k)^{-1}} &\leq 2H\sqrt{d}\Bigl[\frac{1}{2}\log(k+1) + \log(1/\delta)  \notag\\ & \quad + \log \frac{3k[2H\sqrt{dk} + c(\sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)} + 2H\sqrt{d})\sqrt{Hd\log(d/\delta)}]}{H\sqrt{d}} \Bigr]^{1/2} \notag \\
        & \quad + 2\sqrt{2}H\sqrt{d} \notag \\
        & = 2H\sqrt{d}\Bigl[\log \frac{3k\sqrt{k+1} [2H\sqrt{dk} + c(\sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)} + 2H\sqrt{d})\sqrt{Hd\log(d/\delta)}]}{H\sqrt{d}\delta}\Bigr]^{1/2} \notag\\
        & \quad + 2\sqrt{2}H\sqrt{d} \notag \\
        & \leq 2H\sqrt{d}\Bigl[\log \frac{3k\sqrt{k+1}[2H\sqrt{dk} + 2H\sqrt{d}c(\sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)} + 1)\sqrt{Hd\log(d/\delta)}]}{H\sqrt{d}\delta}\Bigr]^{1/2}  \notag \\
        & \quad + 2\sqrt{2}H\sqrt{d} \notag\\
        & = 2H\sqrt{d}\Bigl[\log \frac{3k\sqrt{k+1}[2\sqrt{k}  + 2c(\sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)} + 1)\sqrt{Hd\log(d/\delta)}]}{\delta}\Bigr]^{1/2} \notag \\
        & \quad + 2\sqrt{2}H\sqrt{d} \notag\\
        & \leq c_1 H\sqrt{d}\sqrt{\log(Hdk)/\delta} \notag\\
        & = \sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Notice that in the first equality, the power 1/2 power is missing at the end.Same for the second inequality. Is it possible to start the inequality and the equality slightly more from the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the main issue, I suggest you (a) insert a new `&` alignment point at the start of the first line and (b) insert a new `\\` line break directive before the first instance of `\leq`.

I would also like to suggest that you replace the `align` environment with a nested pair of `equation` and `aligned` environments. This will let you get rid of all `\notag` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert} % "\norm" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&\norm[\bigg]{\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\phi(s_t^i,a_t^i)
 \bigl[ \bigl(\, \overline{V}^{k}_{t+1} 
 - \mathbb{P}_t \overline{V}^{k}_{t+1}\bigr) 
 (s_t^i, a_t^i)\bigr] }_{{(\Sigma_t^k)}^{-1}} \\
&\leq 2H\sqrt{d}\biggl[\frac{1}{2}\log(k+1)+\log(1/\delta)\\ 
&\quad + \log\frac{3k\bigl[2H\sqrt{dk} + c\bigl(\! 
 \sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)} + 2H\sqrt{d}\,\bigr)
 \sqrt{Hd\log(d/\delta)}\,\bigr]}{H\sqrt{d}} \biggr]^{1/2}\\
&\quad + 2\sqrt{2}H\sqrt{d} \\
&= 2H\sqrt{d}\biggl[\log \frac{3k\sqrt{k+1}\,\bigl[
 2H\sqrt{dk} + c\bigl(\!\sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)} 
 + 2H\sqrt{d}\,\bigr)\sqrt{Hd\log(d/\delta)}\,\bigr]}{
 H\sqrt{d}\delta}\biggr]^{1/2} \\
&\quad + 2\sqrt{2}H\sqrt{d} \\
&\leq 2H\sqrt{d}\biggl[\log \frac{3k\sqrt{k+1}\,\bigl[ 
 2H\sqrt{dk} + 2H\sqrt{d}c\bigl(\!\sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)} 
 + 1\bigr)\sqrt{Hd\log(d/\delta)}\,\bigr]}{
 H\sqrt{d}\delta}\biggr]^{1/2} \\
&\quad + 2\sqrt{2}H\sqrt{d} \\
&= 2H\sqrt{d}\biggl[\log \frac{3k\sqrt{k+1}\,\bigl[2\sqrt{k} 
 + 2c\bigl(\!\sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)} + 1\bigr)
 \sqrt{Hd\log(d/\delta)}\,\bigr]}{\delta}\biggr]^{1/2} \\
&\quad + 2\sqrt{2}H\sqrt{d} \\
&\leq c_1 H\sqrt{d}\sqrt{\log(Hdk)/\delta} \\
&= \sqrt{\beta_k(\delta)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for also suggesting how to remove \notag

Comment: the above solution is also creating quite a bit of vertical space before the start of equation. Any suggestion on how to reduce it?

Comment: @hi15 - What you call "quite a bit of vertical space" before the start of the equation may be an artifact of the narrow default measure [that's typography jargon for the width of the text block...] used by LaTeX. If I had loaded the `geometry` package, the text block would have been ever so slightly wider and the vertical whitespace  would have vanished (and the equation number would be placed on the proper line, viz., even with the final row).